# How can I display my element(`class="line"`) over all other elements/div?

Tags: html, css

How can I display my element(`class="line"`) over **all** other elements/div?

```
<div class="line" style="float:left; margin-left:-40px; margin-top:50px; width:30px; color:gray; height:10px; font-size:22px; font-weight:470">_</div>
```

I need to have possibilities to manipulate on `margin-top:50px`

Comment: check out [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Comment: Clearly not by floating the element. It can be done by absolute positioning your element relative to body and increasing the z-index.

Comment: so be carreful at the compatibility with the z-index property take a look here http://caniuse.com/#search=z-index and test your code on many browser and devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can give in following ways:

we can add `class="line"` to `position` property
 and mention  `Z-index` property (`layer concept`)

```
.line
{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2
}
.otherclass
{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
```

we should specify both in `Position` property

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `z-index` property of the element. ie

```
.line{
 position:absolute;
 z-index:100;
top : 0;
left: 0
}
```

Comment: ya you need it make postioned absolute. The left property will set it left position, so you don't need to make it float:left

Answer (score 1):

Add z-index to the css styling.

z-index:100;

why do you want to avoid margin-top?