# Why does my div class push other elements on my page?

Tags: html, css

I have a little floating box that when hovered, moves out and shows text, but when i insert it into a page it either gets pushed out of place, or it pushes the whole site down just for it to have space, How can i place a div, without it interfering with the looks of my site?

The code of my css3 animated box: http://goo.gl/hr4vWW

Comment: `position: absolute;`

Comment: Position: absolute disables the animation

Comment: Follow @Enijar Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the div a position of absolute:

```
position:absolute;
z-index:999999;
```

Answer (score 0):

you most change div position ...
http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: position relative cant use becuse its affects the flow of the content

Answer (score 0):

You nedd to use `Position: absolute` and position your div using top and left attribute

Why we need to give position absolute ? Because absolute positioning  won't affect the flow of the page contents. it forms a new layer. By using `index` value you can layer it accordingly

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/g83Ew/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can use layering concept for the same .Use css `Z-index` property

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704496/how-can-i-display-my-elementclass-line-over-all-other-elements-div/20704708#20704708) .

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/b93w8/)