# How to send this image to front and set the bg to black

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a function of button call the Id image . When the page is loading I want to let a background `div` image to can not click and image send to front of all the `div`.  What
style should I add ?

```
<span id="divImage" style="display:none;" >  
   <img src="Image/Icon/loading.gif" />  
</span>
```

Comment: To set something on top of another element you need a higher z-index. Might want to also look at position:absolute. Include some more code for a more complete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.Use  the `Position`  and `z-index` property

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manojmcet/hLEgA/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704496/how-can-i-display-my-elementclass-line-over-all-other-elements-div/20704708#20704708. See the link..

Answer (score 1):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/U2Mh9/

**CSS:-**

```
.hide {visibility: hidden;}
.reshow {visibility: visible;}
```

**HTML:-**

```
<span class="hide" id="divImage" >  
   <img class="reshow" src="http://www.ppimusic.ie/images/loading_anim.gif" />  
</span>
```

Comment: @Mickey - Does this answer your query?

Comment: i want make the divimage set to front