# Can an image cover a table in html?

Tags: html, css, image, html-table

I'm having problem in making the table hide under the picture. Please visit the link below.

Is there any way to hide a table behind a picture? Like the text wrapping in the microsoft word (infront of text) wherein the front is showing the picture and at the back (hidden) is the table. Btw. to give more idea. I would like to hide the table behind the picture because my picture has a hover animation that when you hover to it, the picture will move away and therefore revealing the table (that's my concept)

[image]

my HTML:
 http://prntscr.com/2dkork
and
http://prntscr.com/2dkotb

```
    .sidepan img {
margin-left: 0px;
-webkit-transition: margin 1s ease;
-moz-transition: margin 1s ease;
-o-transition: margin 1s ease;
-ms-transition: margin 1s ease;
transition: margin 1s ease;
}

.sidepan img:hover {
  margin-left: -2000px;
}
```

Comment: what yaar, plz show the HTML........

Comment: http://prntscr.com/2dkork

Comment: http://prntscr.com/2dkotb

Comment: see the link ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704496/how-can-i-display-my-elementclass-line-over-all-other-elements-div/20704708#20704708

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

Use higher `z-index` on the image as compared to the table. For better control, wrap the table in a `div` to avoid bleeding in case table contents overrun. Provide a size to both the image and table to match each other. Use absolute positioning to place them neatly on top of each other.

See this fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/cY3bu/1/**

```
div {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px; left: 1px;
    z-index: 1;
}
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px; left: 1px;
    z-index: 2;  
    -webkit-transition: left 2s;
}
```

Comment: @user3131639: please don't edit this answer to include your code. please edit your question to include your code.

Comment: I'm sorry xD new to this site and so confused (first time site) didn't noticed

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2"></div>
     <table>
        <tr>stuff</tr>
           <td>stuff</td>
     </table>
</div>
```

Lets say you have the above html.

Then you could do this css for div2

```
#div2 {
   position: absolute;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background: url("/myimage.jpg");
}

#div1:hover #div2 {
   height: 0px;
   width: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<table>
    <td class="td">
        <span>Hello...<span>
    </td>
<table>

<style>
.td{
      background-image: url('../somepath.png');
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
}
.td span{
    display:none;
}
.td:hover
{
    background: none;
}
.td:hover span{
      display:block;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Simple :-

```
table {z-index: 0;}

img {z-index: 1;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Easily use this:
style.css :

```
<style type="text/css">
.myTableBg { width:180px;
background:#dedede url(/pix/web_graphics/free_website_graphics/background_patterns/101Emboss8.gif) repeat;
border-collapse:collapse; 
}
.myTableBg td, .myTableBg th { border:2px solid white;padding:5px; }
</style>
<!-- Place the above styles between the document's <head></head> tags -->
<table class="myTableBg">
<tr>
<th>Table header</th><th>Table header</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Table cell 1</td><td>Table cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Table cell 3</td><td>Table cell 4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Table cell 5</td><td>Table cell 6</td>
</tr>
</table>
```